# cropper not work if the image be data

Tags: html, image, upload

I want to crop image when the user upload it, and after cropping I want to save it in database.
I want to use cropper or cropperjs to do it.
if I use an image that is in server everything is fine but when I want to use the uploaded file the cropper doesnt work.

```
<input type="file" id="fileinput" accept="image/*" />
<button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">Large modal</button>
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" id="gallery">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myLargeModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts{

    @*<link href="~/lib/cropperjs/dist/cropper.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="~/lib/cropperjs/dist/cropper.js"></script>*@
    <link href="~/lib/cropper/dist/cropper.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/lib/cropper/dist/cropper.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            var image;//= document.getElementById('image');
            var cropper;


            $("#btn").click(function (event) {
                cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toBlob(function (blob) {
                    var formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append('croppedImage', blob);
                    $.ajax('/Home/Upload', {
                        method: "POST",
                        data: formData,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        success: function () {
                            console.log('Upload success');
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            console.log('upload Error');
                        }
                    })
                });
            });
        }
        var uploadfiles = document.querySelector('#fileinput');
        uploadfiles.addEventListener('change', function () {
            var files = this.files;
            if (files.length > 0) {
                previewImage(this.files[0]);
                image = document.getElementById('image');

                $('#image').cropper({
                    aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                    viewMode: 1,
                    autoCropArea: 1,
                    minContainerWidth: 700,
                    minContainerHeight:600
                });
            }

        }, false);
        function previewImage(file) {
            var galleryId = "gallery";

            var gallery = document.getElementById(galleryId);
            var imageType = /image.*/;

            if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {
                alert("File Type must be an image");
            }

            var thumb = document.createElement("div");
            thumb.classList.add('thumbnail'); // Add the class thumbnail to the created div

            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.id = "image";
            img.style = "max-width:100%";
            //img.src = "images/banner1.svg"; //if I use this line everything is fine!!!!
            img.file = file;
            thumb.appendChild(img);
            gallery.innerHTML = '';
            gallery.appendChild(thumb);

            // Using FileReader to display the image content
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (function (aImg) { return function (e) { aImg.src = e.target.result; }; })(img);
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);

        }
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I don't know why I use alot of my time to find it this easy problem.
anyways I write it here for anyone that will need it in future.
the problem is that after reader set the data to image the cropper is not set. to do it we should have something like this.

```
reader.onloadend = (function () {
                $('#image').cropper({
                    aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                    viewMode: 1,
                    autoCropArea: 1,
                    minContainerWidth: 700,
                    minContainerHeight: 600
                });
            });
```